# How do I make increment worksheet and formula work in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I make ver 2 formula work in Google Sheets?

Working formula (ver 1):

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('08/10'!$A$4:$A$203,'08/11'!$D$4:$D$203 = E4),"新入")
```

Above formula is perfectly working but I need to automate things so the date 08/11 should be changed to the value represented in A2 cell.
So, A2 cell is  `=TODAY() - 1`# yesterday data set

Not working formula that needs your review (ver 2):

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(CONCATENATE("'",TEXT($A$2),"'"&!$A$4:$A$203),'($A$2)'!$D$4:$D$203 = E4),"新入")
```

I tried to play with formula but failed. I also tried INDIRECT functions but could not write it properly.

Here is I have shared a link to spread sheet for easy reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uqTUjoT978AyNU7TeBfVbcWDQ_aAamC7d51UB8gdLBk/edit#gid=0

Green highlight is working formula but needs update
Yellow highlight is ERROR formula that needs your assistance.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(A2,"MM/dd")&"'!$A$4:$A$203"),INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(A2,"MM/dd")&"'!$D$4:$D$203") = E4),"新入")
```

Comment: Dear idfurw Thank you for your quick response. I have added formula to B21 in shared spreadsheet but it returns me wrong data. It should be 19. Would you please have a look, what is wrong with this formula : =IFERROR(FILTER(INDIRECT(TEXT($A$2,"MM/dd")&"!$A$4:$A$203"),INDIRECT(TEXT($A$2,"MM/dd")&"'!$D$4:$D$203") = E21),"新入")

Comment: Sorry, corrected. I have missed the quotes.

Comment: Please make sure the date in `A2` is `8/10`. It is now `8/11` in my time zone.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and time! Amazing speed and skills.